# How can a string be coerced into tez using Liquidity?

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

Documentation states the following:

```
tez : an unbounded positive float of Tezzies, written either with a tz suffix (1.00tz, etc.) or as a string with type coercion ("1.00" : tez).
```

Yet the following example in Liquidity produces an error:

```
if amount < ("5.00": tez) then
   Current.failwith "Not enough money, at least 5tz to vote"
```

[image: Liquidity compile error]

While type coercion for `nat` works as expected:
[image]

[Github issue can be found here](https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity/issues/173)

Comment: what is the type and value of amount on line 12?

Comment: You can try the example mentioned in the question here (demo.liq):
http://www.liquidity-lang.org/zeronet/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So apparently, this feature is no longer available in Liquidity, and the docs are incorrect in this case. You can read a reply from Liquidity Lead Dev [here](https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity/issues/173).